# Incorporate a voltage controlled current source in a circuit design

Tags: voltage, current, analog, source

The voltage controlled current source as below where VC is the controlled voltage, I_probe3 (I_probe1) is the current controlled by VC

[image]

[image]

How do I incorporate this voltage controlled current source in the design below?

I am going to draw current from the Vnode from the circuit I designed

Somehow I can't figure out the geometry to get these two VCCS in my circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

[image: VCCS]

[image: replacement]

Don't forget that:

- `V_DC` is not included in the VCCS, it just represents the controlling voltage;
- these need to have the `B` point grounded, or it will not work (you will need a differential probe across the sensor resistor, `R3`).

Also, `I_Probe3` is **not** your controlled current, `I_Probe1` is. `I_Probe3` is quite useless there.

Comment: I think something is not right. I need to draw the current from Vnode, but according to you, point A does not have current running thru (I_probe2 and I_probe4 are zero), thus point A is not Vnode. What I need is the current drawn from Vnode.

Comment: Is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZMui.png) more clear?

Comment: Yes, I see, but in this way I need to apply an positive voltage to Vnode to let the current flow. This is not as expected to my original thought. I was thinking to create a current sink independent of the voltage of the Vnode, so with the current drawn from Vnode and the overall resistance above Vnode, I can calculate the characteristic impedance of the transmission line. Does it make sense to you?

Comment: @gibaicao What you've *thought* and what you've *asked* are, it seems, two different things. I've answered your question, given your pictures. If what you want is to "glue" together the two pictures, that's the way to do it. Otherwise, if you want a current source that disobeys the limitations of the supply (of the node it draws current from) then your only alternative is an *ideal* current source which, usually in SPICE, is found as a primitive element. No idea whether your program has it, or not (but since it has a VCCS, I think it does).